# Solving system of ODEs dropping one component of general solution

Tags: differential-equations, calculus-and-analysis, numerical-value

---

### Question:

I want to solve the following system of differential equations:

```
odeM2 = 1/2*sigma*Vm''[x] + ((delta*a0)/a1 - a1*x)*Vm'[x] - em*Vm[x] == -((2*x - 2*lambda*ep*(a0 + a1*x))/(em - ep));
odeP2 = 1/2*sigma*Vp''[x] + ((delta*a0)/a1 - a1*x)*Vp'[x] - ep*Vp[x] == -((-2*x + 2*em*(a0 + a1*x)* lambda)/(em - ep));
```

Since these are second order non-homogeneous differential equations, the solution is given by the sum of the general solution to the homogeneous equation and a particular solution to the non-homogeneous equation. What I need to do is solve this system but drop the Hermite component of the general solution to the homogeneous equation of `odeM` (I will show later that the solution found in this way still satisfies the differential equation).

Since I drop one of the components of the the general solution to the homogeneous equation of `odeM`, the system only contains three constants. To find these constants, I want to use the following boundary conditions to solve following boundary conditions:

```
Ic1 = em*Vm[xhat] + ep*Vp[xhat] == 0;
Ic2 = em*Vm'[xhat] + ep*Vp'[xhat] == 0;
Ic3 = Vm[xhat] + Vp[xhat] == (2*theta)/((epsilon - 1) (1 + curlyphi))*xhat;
```

*Is there a way to solve this system in a more efficient way compared to my approach below, which still yields to a result that does not compute (i.e. it's taking more than two hours)?*

Finally, I want to use a fourth boundary condition to back out `xhat`:

```
Ic4 = Vm'[xhat] + Vp'[xhat] == (2*theta)/((epsilon - 1) (1 + curlyphi));
```

*A numerical approach is acceptable. What I care is to find `xhat`.*

---

### My approach:

**odeM2**

General solution homogeneous

```
SolGeneralHomoM = DSolveValue[odeM2[[1]] == 0, Vm[x], x] // FullSimplify
```

Particular solution nonhomogeneous via variation of parameters method

```
a = 1/2*sigma;
y1 = First@Cases[SolGeneralHomoM, C[1]*any_ :> any];
y2 = First@Cases[SolGeneralHomoM, C[2]*any_ :> any];
f = odeM2[[2]];
W = Wronskian[{y1, y2}, x];
SolParticularNonHomoM = (-y1*Integrate[y2*f/(a*W), x] + y2*Integrate[y1*f/(a*W), x]) // FullSimplify
```

Test solution

```
FinalSolM = SolGeneralHomoM + SolParticularNonHomoM // FullSimplify;
SolM = Vm -> Function[{x}, Evaluate[FinalSolM]];
odeM2 /. SolM // FullSimplify
```

**odeP2**

General solution homogeneous

```
SolGeneralHomoP = DSolveValue[odeP2[[1]] == 0, Vp[x], x] // FullSimplify
```

Drop the Hermite component

```
SolGeneralHomoP = C[2] Hypergeometric1F1[ep/(2 a1), 1/2, (a1^2 x - a0 delta)^2/(a1^3 sigma)]
```

Particular solution nonhomogeneous via comparing coefficients

```
odeP2 /. Vp -> (h0 + h1 # &) /. Equal -> Subtract;
eqn = CoefficientList[%, x];
solh = Solve[eqn == 0, {h0, h1}][[1]]
Simplify[odeP2 /. Vp -> (h0 + h1 # &) /. solh]
SolParticularNonHomoP = h0 + h1 x /. solh
```

Test solution

```
FinalSolP = SolGeneralHomoP + SolParticularNonHomoP // FullSimplify;
SolP = Vp -> Function[{x}, Evaluate[FinalSolP]];
odeP2 /. SolP // FullSimplify
```

Rename the third constant

```
FinalSolP = FinalSolP /. C[2] -> C[3]
```

Define new variables for the boundary conditions

```
Jx[x_] = em*FinalSolM + ep*FinalSolP;
Jxx[x_] = em*D[FinalSolM, x] + ep*D[FinalSolP, x];
Jpi[x_] = FinalSolM + FinalSolP;
Jpipi[x_] = D[FinalSolM, x] + D[FinalSolP, x];
```

Find the constants

```
constants = Solve[{Jx[xhat] == 0, Jxx[xhat] == 0, Jpi[xhat] == (2*theta)/((epsilon - 1)*(1 + curlyphi))*xhat}, {C[1], C[2], C[3]}];
```

Substitute the constants into the variables

```
SolJx[x_] = Jx[x] /. constants[[1]];
SolJxx[x_] = Jxx[x] /. constants[[1]];
SolJpi[x_] = Jpi[x] /. constants[[1]];
SolJpipi[x_] = Jpipi[x] /. constants[[1]];
```

Define the parameters

```
delta = 2/100;
epsilon = 3/2;
curlyphi = 5;
xi = 5/1000;
lambda = 1/2;
N[c = lambda*(epsilon - 1)*(1 + curlyphi)];
N[theta = c + 0.05];(*3/2*)
sigma = (20/100)^2;
mu = 5/100;
sigmaA = 10/100;
rn = delta + mu - sigmaA^2;
em = (delta*theta - Sqrt[delta^2*theta^2 + 4*theta*(epsilon - 1)*(1 + curlyphi)])/(2*theta);
ep = (delta*theta + Sqrt[delta^2*theta^2 + 4*theta*(epsilon - 1)*(1 + curlyphi)])/(2*theta);
a1 = (-delta*theta + Sqrt[delta^2*theta^2 + 4*theta*(epsilon - 1)*(1 + curlyphi)])/(2*theta);
a0 = -((xi + rn - 1/2*sigma - sigmaA*Sqrt[sigma])/(delta + a1))*a1;
a = (-delta*theta + Sqrt[delta^2*theta^2 + 4*lambda*(epsilon - 1)^2*(1 + curlyphi)^2])/(2*lambda*(epsilon - 1)*(1 + curlyphi));
```

**Find xhat**

Back out `xhat`

```
Solxhat = NSolve[SolJpipi[xhat] == (2*theta)/((epsilon - 1)*(1 + curlyphi)), xhat]
```

Unfortunately, this last line does not compute.

Comment: Have you tried `FindRoot` instead of `NSolve`?